# Is there a way to show users next steps after direct add-on installation from web page?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-on

I have recently published a new Google Sheets add-on and found difficulties in how to indicate users what to do next after installation.

There are two ways of add-on installation currently available :

1. Open "Add-on" -> "Get add-ons" menu, search for an add-on and install it.
2. Directly access the add-on web page like the link below and install it.

   [https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/[add-on](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/%5Badd-on) name]/[add-on id]

For case 1, I can pop up a dialog or sidebar upon `onInstall` event, and show instructions to users, such as open an add-on menu, access an online manual and etc.

However, for case 2, I believe there is no action or event available after the add-on installation. It seems that many users are lost at this point and give up proceeding to the next step.

Is there any way to receive an event similar to `onInstall` and notify users what to do next for case 2 ?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. The question looks what here is called "primarily opinion-based" which are not allowed here. Please [edit] the question make it fit the guidelines stated on [ask].

Comment: @Rubén Just because there is a "best way" or "other ways" in the question doesn't make the question "opinion based".  Are the answers likely to be opinion based and not "fact-based"? Is "this question likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations."? I don't think so. I disagree with closing a question just because it is asking for  "multiple ways" or "best way" somewhere in the question?

Comment: I totally agree with the questioner. For case 2, many users seem lost after installation since they don't know what to do next.

For case 1, I'm hoping that Google Sheet has a parameter to open the marketplace dialog directly so that we can advertise something like below to potential users :

https://sheets.new/?add-on-id=[your add-on id]

Then, after installation, we can make use of "onInstall" event to pop up a dialog or sidebar to guide users.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to get the notice of the user in case of case2(Directly access the add-on web page like the link below and install it) is to create the custom addOn menu. When the addon is `INSTALLED` and NOT `ENABLED`, `onOpen()` runs in `AuthMode.NONE`. In this authorization mode, you can add menus, but not capture the user attention directly through pop ups.

#### References:

- [Editor Addon authorization lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle)
- [Creating Menus for editor Add ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/menus)