# How to call third party api to verify user email for cross authentication after the Google Slides add-on installation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I want to verify the user email through third-party APIs. For example, if the user is our CRM member, at the time of add-on installation, I want to see if his email ID is in our system or not.

To do this I tried to call the `licenseAuth()` method in `onInstall()` method but seems, the `licenseAuth()` is not calling inside the onInstall() method when I am reloading the slide.

As its development mode, running Addon via Script Editor and I still had not submitted to publish slide addons. So I am reloading the slide and checking the addon process again.

Do you have any other ideas to add and test it like we are installing the addons and then email verification?

```
function onOpen(event) {
  myMenus();
}

function myMenus(){
  var slideUi = SlidesApp.getUi();
}

function onInstall(event) {
  onOpen(event);
}

function licenseAuth() {
    // I will open a model less dialog box to verify the process after the installation of the addon


    //Calling alert just for testing
    var ui = SlidesApp.getUi();
        var result = ui.alert(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), 'Are you sure you want to continue?',ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
}
```

Comment: Reload should only trigger onOpen. onInstall usually runs in fullauth. So you shouldn't have a problem. But onInstall will only run if installed from the store, when using the slides. So, for users who install it  when the document is not open, you still need to use `onOpen` and request authorization.

Comment: So your mean, without Publishing it can not work like I am trying to do custom auth after add-ons install. Is there no any temp way to play like in real environment ? @TheMaster

Comment: I haven't tested this, but yes, I don't think  there's a way.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63497532

Comment: @BobKris Yes, this is what I would suggest when the user is trying to click on the main menu, show something like user alert or modal box if any subscription is not verified by your CRM, more you can show your plans link to subscribe. (if you are running any paid addons) as suggested by OlegValter and TheMaster (in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/50346220#50346220 )